# Have child be at 100% height of a parent with overflow:auto

Tags: html, css, scroll, height

I'm trying to make a mask over a list of elements contained in a fixed width and height parent. The parent is set to overflow:auto. When we add elements to the list, the parent scrolls, but the mask keeps its original height, and I would like it to fill the parent all the way to the bottom of the scroll.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7sRh/

html:

```
<div id="test">
<div id="mask">&nbsp;</div>
<ul>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li class="over">Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#test{
width:150px;
height:200px;
background-color:#eee;
overflow:auto;
position:relative;
}
#mask{
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
min-height:100%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
z-index:1;
}
li{
background-color:white;
}

.over{
position:relative;
z-index:2;
}
```

Some elements need to be over the mask, and a javascript solution would be acceptable, although html/css is better.

I searched the web for an answer and couldn't find it, I hope some of you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7sRh/3/

```
$('#mask').css('height', $('ul').css('height') );​
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery:

```
$('#mask').height($('#test')[0].scrollHeight);
```

JavaScript (straight up)

```
document.getElementById('mask').style.height = document.getElementById('test').scrollHeight + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you overcomplicating this? Set overs background colour to white and the li to the grey. Same result and doesn't matter how many elements there are. Is there some reason you need the extra div and code?  http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/Z7sRh/2/

```
li{
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.over{
background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: The idea behind the mask is to render the elements unclickable, they are not interactive in the example to try and provide a minimal example.